# Taylor expansion proof $e^{-x}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus

This is a question that follows doubts that showed up in another question. I have tried to use Taylor expansions to prove the following unsuccessfully:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$

in order to prove:$e^{-x}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$

Could someone prove it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Binomial theorem is the way here!!.

Comment: Closely related to [this MSE POST](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989676/why-is-ex-lim-n-to-infty-left1-fracxn-rightn?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$s = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n$$
then
$$\ln(s) = \lim_{n\to \infty} n\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)}{1/n}$$
Using l'Hopital's rule, 
$$= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-1}(-x/n^2)}{-1/n^2} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x}{1+\frac{x}{n}} = x$$
and so $s = e^x$.